# Require a file within a route to run a query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Im trying to set up my routes and then include a "content" file that would run a query

```
app.get('/participants', function(req, res, next) {
  var participants = require('./content/participants');
});
```

and then the participants file:

```
const db = database.connect('olmsdb.1sserver.com', 'campyio');
db.raw('SELECT * FROM participants').then(function(results) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(results));

  return results;
  db.destroy();
});
```

The goal here is to hit the /participants route and then run the the select query and send the query results.

Comment: Calling `db.destroy()` after `return` won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require()` doesn't work like `source(..)` or `execute` in other languages. The code in it only execute once when first required. Then the module is cached.

You need to return functions and classes in a module file, using `module.exports` etc.

To do this:

`participants.js`:

```
const db = database.connect('olmsdb.1sserver.com', 'campyio');

exports.getParticipants = function() {
   return db.raw('SELECT * FROM participants');
}
```

`app.js`:

```
var participants = require('./content/participants');

app.get('/participants', function(req, res, next) {
  participants.getParticipants().then(function(results) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
      next();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that code in an exported function so that you can call it with the request & response every time you get a request.

That means there is no point in `require()`ing it inside your route handler.

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Charles: How would you write a function? Learn the basics of Javascript syntax.  Also learn about `exports` and Node / CommonJS modules.